# Nested Promise in Promise each

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, sails.js, bluebird

Can someone explain why this doesn't work as I expect it?

I am trying to return only the id of the created or updated items to use in the Promise.each().then(). This is necessary because create returns an object and update an array of objects.

```
Promise.each(items, function(item){
  if(...item doesn\'t exist...)
    return Item.create(item)
     .then(function (created) {
        return created.id;
        ///HOW DO I GET THIS ID ONLY?
      });
  else {
   return Item.update(item)
     .then(function (updated) {
        return updated[0].id;
        ///AND THIS ID?
      });
   }

}).then(function(result) {
  sails.log("THIS SHOULD BE AN ID" + JSON.stringify(result));
});
```

result is the whole created object, instead of just the id. I want to return an array of just the updated ids. Apparently nesting promises is bad, but I don't know how i could simplify this.

Comment: `Promise.each` in 2.x returns the original array, returning inside the iterator only serves as signaling what promise to await before iterating the next index. What are you trying to do ? which id are you trying to return and why that id?

Comment: so you're saying I can't?

Comment: I have edited my question, i hope it is clear what i want to do now

Comment: I still don't get it, what if many items are created? What id will you then return and why? It looks like multiple ids should be returned I.E. an array - not "an id".

Comment: yes, you are correct, that's what i meant. one id per item. Doesn't the then() function get called once for each item in each()?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use `.each` use `.map` to map a list of items to a list of items:

```
Promise.map(items, function(item){
  if(...item doesn\'t exist...)
    return Item.create(item).get("id"); // get is a shortcut to .then(fn(x){ r x.id; })
  else {
   return Item.update(item).get(0).get(id);
}).then(function(result) {
  sails.log("Here is the array of all IDs + JSON.stringify(result));
});
```

If you want to go over them one by one and wait for them, you can chain a second `.map`. If you want to set to do them sequentially (much slowe) - `.map` also takes a concurrency  parameter.

As Esailija said - in 3.0 the behavior of `each` changes to return the results so your original code would have been ineffective but would have actually worked in 3.0 .

Comment: Didnt know about the get function.It is a lifesaver. This works beautifully. I'd give you a cookie if I could